# Изменения в ключе меняют словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, память, dict

Есть код, аналогичный данному:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.i)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.i == other.i

a = A(1)
m = {a: '1', A(2): '2'}
m[A(1)] # => '1'
a.i = 5
m[A(1)] # KeyError, а хочется '1'
```

Подскажите, как добиться желаемого поведения? Понятно, что можно использовать что-то такое:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy
a = A(1)
m = {copy(a): '1', A(2): '2'}
m[A(1)] # => '1'
a.i = 5
m[A(1)] # '1'
```

Но выглядит странно и, кажется, должно есть много памяти. Есть ли какое-то стандартное рещение?

---

Ситуация примерно такая:

```
m = {i: f(i) for i in some_list}

def get_mutated_value(smt):
    return m[m[smth].mutate()]
```

Comment: По-моему, использовать в качестве ключа что-то мутабельное — в принципе сомнительная идея, чреватая регулярными выстрелами в ноги поддерживающим такой код

Comment: если вы хотите менять ключ и при этом хотите предсказуемого и корректного результата вам всегда надо будет (хотя бы под капотом) пересобирать контейнер, так что в одну строку это не сделать

Comment: В самой постановке задачи противоречие. У вас для объектов класса A эквивалентность задана на основе атрибута i. Соответственно, если вы меняете атрибут i, то вы уже не можете ожидать, что этот объект будет считаться тем же самым. Если хочется менять i, то эквивалентность и хэш нужно привязать к чему-то другому. Например, к id объекта. Или к первоначальному значению i, которое будет запоминаться отдельно и никогда не меняться.

Comment: @Xander Первоначальное значение, кстати - хороший вариант. А вот id объекта - нет, ведь у `A(1)` всегда будет новый `id`, такой ключ никогда не найдётся в словаре.

Comment: @Xander, честно говоря, я не вижу противоречия. `i` - это все состояние объекта, если у двух объектов равны `i`, то их следует считать равными во всех возможных смыслах. И наоборот - если два объекта были равны, а потом у одного поменялось `i`, то они должны считаться разными.

Comment: @Rennorb И как это согласуется с вашим же кодом: `a.i = 5
m[A(1)] # KeyError, а хочется '1'`???

Comment: @Rennorb Если объект `a` стал другим, не таким как `A(1)`, то как мы можем считать, что как ключ в словаре `a` всё-равно совпадает с `A(1)`? Уж что-то одно. Либо это один объект не смотря на изменение состояния (а значит у него есть ещё какое-то секретное, неизменное состояние), либо это разные объекты и значит разные ключи словаря.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что, при создании словаря, ключем является значение `a_0`. Запрос значения по другому ключу `a = mutate(a_0); m[a]` (`mutate` как-то меняет аргумент и возвращает то, что получилось) может возвращать что угодно, в том чиселе и `KeyError`. Если для какого-то объекта вдруг стало верным равенство `x == a_0`, то `m[x] == m[a_0]`.

Comment: Но, судя по вашему единодушию, стоит действительно сделать ключи иммутабельными.

Comment: @Rennorb Ну так смотрите мой ответ, там есть разные варианты. Вы ведь хотите, чтобы ключ не менялся, значит вам надо как-то зафиксировать значение ключа на момент создания словаря. Это можно сделать разными способами, я несколько вариантов предложил.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, можно вот так легко добиться требуемого поведения в этом конкретном случае, но не очень понимаю, в чём глубокий смысл.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.i)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

a = A(1)
m = {a: '1', A(2): '2'}
m[A(1)] # => '1'
a.i = 5
print(m[A(1)]) # => '1'
print(m[A(2)]) # => '2'
```

Если что, суть тут в том, что хэш объекта считается только в момент помещения элемента в словарь, а потом проверяется только `eq`.

Вариант реализации решения, предложенного Xander - с сохранением первоначального состояния, так, думаю, более правильно (при всей кривизне ситуации):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
        self._i = i
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._i)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._i == other._i
```

А, вот вам ещё один смешной вариант, даже не надо менять ваш код класса. Просто используйте в качестве ключа словаря поле класса, а не класс:

```
a = A(1)
m = {a.i: '1', A(2).i: '2'}
m[A(1).i] # => '1'
a.i = 5
m[A(1).i] # => '1'
```

Comment: А в случае совпадения хэшей разные ключи будут перезатирать друг друга?

Comment: @Xander Конечно. И поиск в словаре будет ложно "срабатывать" при совпадении хэша и перезатираться будут.

Comment: Вернее, не ключи, а значения будут перезатираться

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__ `The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value`. У вас для равных объектов допускается неравные хеши, результат непредсказуем. Это вредный, даже деструктивный совет. Единственным правильным ответом на вопрос ОПа может быть: вы хотите странного, не делайте так.

Comment: @extrn Да я согласен. В любом случае автор вопроса хочет странного и любые варианты тут будут извратом.